# 500 (Internal Server Error) after deploy MVC project to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, iis

My MVC project works well under VS2015 (LocalDB+IISexpress) also I use EntityFramework in this project.

**Goal:** Now I want to try to publish it to local IIS.(ver.10) 
Then I attached the database in Microsoft SQL Management Studio 2016. 
I added the project in IIS.

**Problem:**
When I call API controller it returns 500 error.

```
    {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The underlying provider failed on ConnectionString.","ExceptionType":"System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException","StackTrace":"   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObjectInternal(Object value, Type type, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at WebApplication1.Controllers.BaseAPIController.ToJSON(Object obj)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()","InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The given path's format is not supported.","ExceptionType":"System.NotSupportedException","StackTrace":"   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String fullPath)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.QuickDemand(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String fullPath, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
   at System.Data.Common.ADP.GetFullPath(String filename)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ExpandDataDirectory(String keyword, String value, String& datadir)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.SetConnectionString(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)"}}
```

In web.config my connection string is:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="UserDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/UserDbEntities.csdl|res://*/UserDbEntities.ssdl|res://*/UserDbEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\UserDB.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

In IIS in the "Connection Strings" settings the connection string after deploy looks like this:

```
metadata=res://*/UserDbEntities.csdl|res://*/UserDbEntities.ssdl|res://*/UserDbEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\UserDB.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"
```

I change only source from *source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB* to *source=DesktopName\MSSQLSERVER2016*

Comment: `"ExceptionMessage":"The underlying provider failed on ConnectionString.","ExceptionType":"System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException" ...` Please update your post with that **entire** message.

Comment: Updated the error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you can open the database in Visual Studio, via the SQL Server Object Explorer pane, you can right-click on the database and choose "Properties". In the Properties pane, there will be a line with the connection string.

Otherwise, you'll need to manually construct the connection string, which for SQL Server, will likely look something like:

```
Data Source=[host];Initial Catalog=[DB];Integrated Security=False;User Id=[user];Password=[password];MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

Comment: I've tried to put this connection string in IIS `Data Source=DESKTOP-Name\MSSQLSERVER2016;AttachDbFilename=C:\Projects\angular-cli-mvc\angular-cli-mvc\WebApplication1\App_Data\UserDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework` but then the error changes to "keyword not supported" `"{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Keyword not supported: 'data source'.","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException","StackTrace":...`